# Linux Clang and Objective-C base library

Tags: objective-c, clang, gnustep

I have been experimenting with Objective-C using GCC + GNUstep on an Ubuntu system.

Now regarding the LLVM Clang compiler, what kind of *step library does it offer? Does it use the GNUstep on the Apple Cocoa? I am mostly interested in the base library - collections, streams, etc. The website doesn't give much information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LLVM Clang is a compiler. It is completely independent from the Cocoa / Cocoa Touch frameworks on OS X / iOS, or any other frameworks or platform, for that matter.

Answer (score 9):

Like MKroehnert and puzzle said, neither LLVM Clang nor GCC actually come with a set of frameworks. GCC comes with only a small runtime that doesn't provide `NSArray`, `NSString`, not even `NSObject`.

Frameworks are provided by, for example:

- [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/)
- [Cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org/)
- [Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/)
- [ObjFW](https://webkeks.org/objfw/)

ObjFW is the lightest of them all, but on any UNIX, I'd recommend you go the GNUstep route.

Answer (score 2):

Like puzzle said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392186/linux-clang-and-objective-c-base-library/6392224#6392224) clang is a compiler like gcc.
On linux you can also use clang instead of gcc together with the GNUstep libraries (which provide the NS* classes you were asking about).

For more information see [GNUstep Objc2 FAQ](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/ObjC2_FAQ) or [this blogpost](http://blog.vucica.net/2010/12/getting-objective-c-2-0-to-work-on-debians-gnustep-with-clang.html) for example.

Comment: Thank you, that blog post was very helpful. I was not sure whether the foundation framework (NS* classes) was dependent upon the language runtime implementation. Since GNUstep and GCC are both GNU, and also up until recently there was no other ObjC compiler for linux, I supposed that there could be some strong coupling between them.

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, LLVM Clang is just a compiler. But you can have all the modern features of Objective-C 2.0 on Ubuntu using Clang, the modern GNUstep Objective-C 2.0 runtime and GNUstep itself. Have a look here for a how to:

http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/GNUstep_under_Ubuntu_Linux

That page is maintained by the GNUstep developers and contains bash scripts to compile and install everything needed for Objective-C 2.0 from scratch for different versions of Ubuntu-Linux using Clang and the GNUstep Objective-C runtime, which can be found here: https://github.com/gnustep/libobjc2 . It would be moot to copy those lengthy scripts to Stackoverflow since they would get out of date sooner or later. So follow that link to get everything from first hand.