# what is (LLVM Clang) ? is it software to code in objective c?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, clang

I want to know what is clang is it a software that I install on my Linux then be able to code on objective c .

if yes how I tried downloading it but couldn’t find any answers there is not even youtube videos it is like unknown.
Any suggestions?

Comment: So you prefer YouTube search instead of google search, eh?

Answer (score 0):

Forget the term "LLVM". You can indeed install the Clang compiler and use it to compile Objective-C. Example, on Ubuntu:

```
> sudo apt-get install clang
> clang myfile.m
```

Clang is a C, C++ and Objective-C compiler. It's a part of the [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) collection of projects, and uses other parts extensively, which explains why you also heard the term "LLVM". As an end-user, though, you shouldn't care - just install and use it.

I'm also guessing you will be interested in [this answer on how to get some basic library to work with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6473972/242762).